# how to change programmatically role of user

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, user-roles

I need to change the role of the user in case the user fills up all the required details from limited to the administrator. However, I need this to be done programmatically so please guide me the way I can make this possible.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
$userId = 2;
$userModel = Mage::getModel('admin/user')->load($userId);
$userModel->setRoleIds(array(2,3,12)) //Role ids array()
        ->setRoleUserId($userModel->getUserId())
        ->saveRelations();
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is for you:

```
      $role = Mage::getModel("admin/role");
      $role->setParent_id(5); //This is role id
      $role->setTree_level(1);
      $role->setRole_type('U');
      $role->setUser_id($user_id); //user id that role need to change
      $role->save();
```